# problem with max in jquery.validate plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I have the code that you can check in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4SCrp/5/

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input id="formfield1" type="text" maxlength="3" value="">
    <br/>
    <input id="formfield2" type="text" maxlength="3" value="">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and th followin script using [jquery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin

```
$("#my_form").validate();

$('#formfield1').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    max: 255
});

$('#formfield2').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    max: 2
});
```

It is supposed to acept a maximum of 255 in the first field and a maximum of 2 in the second. But both give the error "Please enter a value less than or equal to 2." so it takes for all the last `max` defined.

Do you know how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Its `maxlength` you need - not `max` check here -> http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/maxlength#length</strike>

Try specifying the rules as follows :

```
$("#my_form").validate({
    rules: {
        formfield1: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            max: 255
        },
        formfield2: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            max: 2
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: no, ´maxlenght´ will only check the number of characters, not if the value is bigger that a given figure. I want to check that the written value is less than a different figure on each field.

Comment: Edited my answer - sorry !! i actually read the question correctly this time !!

Comment: @David This works fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/4SCrp/7/  - the submit button causes a problem but instant validation is working fine - note the name attribute on the form fields

Comment: I see. The key is that it makes the validation by the **name attribute** instead of by the id. But it could be cases when you may need several elements with the same name and different rules. For that I couldn't reach a solution. Thank you very much Manse!!

Comment: You can use the class if you have single rule for multiple elements

Comment: ussing this i suppose: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules

Comment: Yesterday I tryed using different classes in elements with the same name, to apply different rules to each one. And it happens that if one of the elements with the same name pass the test on submit, the form get submited. So at the end your solution of specifing the rules and apply different names was the better solution. The reason to use the same name was to get easily the POSTed element as an array in the server side processing.